# jQuery extension, can I make this code more elegant?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was writing some custom jQuery plugins and I have the following code
that extends the jQuery:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.extend({    

        pluginOne: function () { return this.each(pluginOneFN) },
        pluginTwo: function () { return this.each(pluginTwoFN) },
        pluginThree: function (p1, p2) {
            return this.each(function() { 
                pluginThreeFN.call(this, p1, p2); 
            });
        }    

    });
})(jQuery);
```

Now the `pluginOne` and `pluginTwo` are OK but `pluginThree` looks messy.

The `pluginThree` requires some parameters, and I was wondering 
is there shorter or more elegant way to write this piece of extension code for plugin 3?

Comment: Nope, that's it. I don't see anything wrong with it though. I presume you find all the anonymous `function()` definitions unsightly? That's just the way JS is, though.

Comment: I don't think it's messy at all, readable, understandable. Perhaps you could use `arguments` to save the characters `p1` and `p2`. But still you have to save it to a local variable, so.. just leave it as is I think.

Comment: Shorter maybe, more elegant is depending on what you regard as elegant. But I think it's good as it is.

Comment: I would make jsut one change. change call to apply so can have room for more number of arguments if needed. if you are certain that there will be only two args i would not change anything.     pluginThree: function (p1, p2) { var args = arguments;
            return this.each(function() { 
                pluginThreeFN.apply(this, args); 
            });
        }

Comment: Just curious: Would this better fit into http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: deffo in the wrong site...

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I can think of is a little reusability improvement. You could introduce a function to initialize plugins in general, supporting arguments.

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.initializePlugin = function(pluginFn, args) {
      return this.each(function() { 
          pluginFn.apply(this, args); 
      });
    };

    $.fn.extend({    
        pluginOne: function () { return this.each(pluginOneFN) },
        pluginTwo: function () { return this.each(pluginTwoFN) },
        pluginThree: function () { return this.initializePlugin(pluginThreeFN, arguments) }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Note that I haven't tested this code, it's only for demonstrating the idea.

Also, if I were creating plugins, I would follow the existing convention of using only one argument, which is some kind of `options` object at initializtion, or a `string` for calling methods. Your method cannot support this, neither can this in my answer. You can check `bootstrap`'s source code for a good skeleton implementation of such a plugin system.

Comment: I was thinking also in this direction, nice!

Comment: Sorry I had a mess in the code, now it should be better.

Comment: Downvoter, could you please review my edits and leave a comment if something is still incorrect?